# Remove duplicates from Dropdownlist with LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with some duplicate items on it. I intended to remove them by using LINQ, but do not know how to do it.

Any suggestions? Thank you so much in advance. BTW, I'm developing in VB.NET.

Comment: what about [distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Add `.Distinct()` at the end of your LINQ query, e.g:

```
var query = 
(from p in theTable
select p.itemID)
.Distinct();
```